# Creation of an Android answer-response app

Tags: java, android

I've created an Android answer-response application that has some questions always presented to the user in the same order. But what I want to do is randomly submit them to avoid user fatigue from using my app.Is there any solution to do that?

Comment: Are  you getting this answer from  Backed also?

Comment: Implememnt in BACKED PART.